# Load custom GIFs in Angular 2

Tags: html, css, angular

I am not able to load my custom GIFs in **Angular 2**. I have tried:

```
<img src="./images/mygif.gif" />
<img [src]="images/mygif.gif" />
```

If it's an image such as PNG and JPG, it shows fine

I also tried loading from css like this:

```
background: url("images/mygif.gif");
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's better to put your images inside src/assets so the build find and attach them to /dist.

And use as :

```
<img src="/assets/images/mygif.gif" />
```

and

```
background: url("/assets/images/mygif.gif");
```

Comment: Ah perfect! Worked like a charm. Thank you!